# Issue in using Loop to find words in Word Doc VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a dynamic list of search words in a column. I want to open a word document and then pull back any found words. For some reason, after it finds its first match, it continues through the code and doesn't pull back any more matches. It should have pulled back 6 words, but it only pulled back the first word in my dynamic list. Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
Sub SearchWord()
Dim odoc As Document
Dim path As String
Dim rng As Word.Range
path = "*MYFILEPATH*"

Dim DS As Worksheet
Dim SS As Worksheet
Set DS = Sheets("Report")
Set SS = Sheets("Search Index")

    With SS
        SSlastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With DS
        dslastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With


Set odoc = Documents.Open(Filename:=path)
Set rng = odoc.Content


For J = 2 To SSlastRow
    sText = SS.Range("B" & J).Value

    With rng.Find
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = sText
    End With
    rng.Find.Execute
    If rng.Find.found = True Then
        DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value = DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value & sText & ";" & " "
    Else
        DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value = DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value
    End If
Next J

odoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: bring the line `Set rng = odoc.Content` within for loop and it may work. After 1st loop `rng` is getting redefined. Also lines `Else` and 
`DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value = DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value` is unnecessary.

Comment: @AhmedAU such a simple fix, it works perfectly now. I was under the impression that if it came before the loop, it would keep it's definition. Thank's for your help! (Also, I'm new here. Anyway I can give your comment an up vote and mark this resolved without someone posting a resolution?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with where you set your rng - which you don't need. Your code could be simplified in other ways, too. Try:

```
Sub SearchWord()
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Dim path As String
path = "*MYFILEPATH*"

Dim DS As Worksheet, SS As Worksheet
Dim SSlastRow As Long, DSlastRow As Long, J As Long
Set DS = Sheets("Report")
Set SS = Sheets("Search Index")

SSlastRow = SS.Cells(SS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
DSlastRow = DS.Cells(DS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set oDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=path, AddToRecentFiles:=False)

For J = 2 To SSlastRow
    sText = SS.Range("B" & J).Value
    With oDoc.Range.Find
        .MatchCase = False
        .Text = sText
        .Execute
        If .Found = True Then DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value = DS.Range("Q" & 2).Value & sText & "; "
    End With
Next J

oDoc.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! You and Ahmed were very helpful!